# How to check for mouse click whilst tool tip is on c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

in the following image generated by my code,

I want the tooltip to show value for each colour whilst my cursor is on it and when I click a particular place on the image i want a dash line to appear on the image.

[image: Ref Bar Image]
this is my code:

```html
RefBar.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(RefBar_MouseMove);
            RefBar.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(RefBar_Click);

private void RefBar_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
         {  
             if (gotMapFirstTime == true)
             {
                 Point LocalMousePosition = RefBar.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
                 MousePointDisplay.SetToolTip(RefBar, WaferMap.getParamValueFromMousePointerXY(LocalMousePosition.X, LocalMousePosition.Y, 1, true).ToString());                  
             }
         }

private void RefBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] bytes2;
            Image image;
            MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
            Point coordinates = me.Location;
            
            WaferMap.RefBarDashLines.Add(coordinates.Y);
            
            int[] rfd = WaferMap.RefBarDashLines.ToArray();
            if (rfd.Length > 2)
            {
                RefBar.Image.Dispose();
                bytes2 = WaferMap.CreateMapReferenceBar(40, 580, 0, 0, 1);
                WaferMap.RefBarDashLines = new List<int>();
                WaferMap.UpperTrackBarLimit = 0.0;
                WaferMap.LowerTrackBarLimit = 0.0;
                pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
                bytes2 = WaferMap.CreateGridImage(120, 120, 9, 9, 5);
                image = Image.FromFile(WaferMapImage);
                pictureBox2.Image = image;
            }
            else if(rfd.Length == 2)
            {
                RefBar.Image.Dispose();
                bytes2 = WaferMap.CreateMapReferenceBarByClick(40, 580, 0, 0, 1);
                pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
                bytes2 = WaferMap.CreateGridImageFilteredByTrackBar(120, 120, 9, 9, 5);
                image = Image.FromFile(WaferMapImage);
                pictureBox2.Image = image;
            }
            else
            {
                RefBar.Image.Dispose();
                bytes2 = WaferMap.CreateMapReferenceBarByClick(40, 580, 0, 0, 1);
            }
            
            image = Image.FromFile(ReferenceBarImage);
            RefBar.Image = image;
            
            MapLowerLimit.Text = coordinates.X.ToString() + " " + coordinates.Y.ToString();
        }
```

in class wafermap we have this:

```html
 public static double getParamValueFromMousePointerXY(int x, int y, int boxSize, bool isRefBarOrHistogram)
        {
            double returnVal = 0.0;
            Point UL;
            Point BR;
            int cellX;
            int invertY;
            int cellY;
            if (isRefBarOrHistogram)
            {
                invertY = -1*(y - RefBarLength);
                return get_YCell_to_ParamValue(invertY, RefBarLength);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (die dd in dieList)
                {
                    cellX = dd.col;
                    cellY = dd.row;
                    UL = new Point(boxSize * (cellX + 2), boxSize * (cellY + 4));
                    BR = new Point((boxSize * (cellX + 2)) + boxSize, (boxSize * (cellY + 4)) + boxSize);
                    if ((UL.X < x && x <= BR.X) && (UL.Y < y && y <= BR.Y))
                    {
                        return dd.ParamValue;
                    }

                }
            }
           
            return returnVal;
        }
public struct die
{
    public int row;
    public int col;
    public int site;
    public string param;
    public double ParamValue;
}
```

the code for the Mouse click event works if the tool tip function is commented off, however when the tooltip function is is invoked for the mouse move function the code doesnt detect or detects after multiple clicks the mouse click event, how do i rectify this?

Comment: Are you doing a longer calculation in your `SetToolTip` method? Everything in the Click handler ist executed in the UI thread. During that time, no other UI operations can be performed. That could result in a click not being recognized. It's hard to tell though without seeing the method. The solution would be to either speed up that method or execute parts of it in the background.

Comment: I have edited the code for your reference, I cant paste the whole code here as it is a very large application, i just wanna know how to invoke the RefBar_Click function whilst the tooltip is on for RefBar_MouseMove function

Comment: the tooltip command is very fast, and I get the correct value whereever the cursor is on the image

Comment: It might be fast, but you are executing it a lot, at every mouse move. Check my reply, that should decouple tooltip display from mouse movement.

Comment: The tooltip is a different window. Make sure it's not intercepting your mouse clicks - the easiest way is to make sure the tooltip is at an offset from the mouse position, so that it isn't under the mouse hotspot. And I'm pretty sure the mouse click doesn't work anyway, since its `EventArgs` are *not* `MouseEventArgs` - mouse click isn't designed for getting the *position* of the mouse click; indeed, there is no position that is "the click position" - the only granularity you get is on the control/window level (think holding the mouse down on a button an dragging). Use mouse up/down instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that the `getParamValueFromMousePointerXY` takes so long to execute that your UI thread is blocked from execution any other task, such as handling your clicks.

You can offload the work to a background task and marshal setting the tooltip back to the UI thread:

```
Task.Run(() => {
    string paramValue = WaferMap.getParamValueFromMousePointerXY(LocalMousePosition.X, LocalMousePosition.Y, 1, true).ToString();
    MethodInvoker setTooltip = delegate() {
        MousePointDisplay.SetToolTip(RefBar, paramValue);
    };
    RefBar.Invoke(setTooltip);
});
```

What you basically are doing here is to execute `getParamValueFromMousePointerXY` in a background task, while you continue to execute `SetToolTip` in the UI thread.

The only caveat here is that you possibly run a lot of background tasks here that will be in a race condition to set the tool tip. You can prevent that by using a cancellation token. You define a variable for a `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
CancellationTokenSource tooltipSource = null;
```

You can use this cancellation token source to prevent old updates to the tooltip:

```
tooltipSource?.Cancel();
tooltipSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task tooltipTask = new Task((tokenObj) => {
    string paramValue = WaferMap.getParamValueFromMousePointerXY(LocalMousePosition.X, LocalMousePosition.Y, 1, true).ToString();
    ((CancellationToken)tokenObj).ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    MethodInvoker setTooltip = delegate() {
        MousePointDisplay.SetToolTip(RefBar, paramValue);
    };
    RefBar.Invoke(setTooltip);
}, tooltipSource.Token);
tooltipTask.Start();
```

With this you should reduce the number of updates to your tooltip.

Of course you can pass the `CancellationToken` to `getParamValueFromMousePointerXY` and cancel the task even earlier.

Comment: You should still seriously consider optimizing getParamValueFromMousePointerXY. Even if you're not blocking the UI thread, if a tooltip doesn't appear instantaneously, the UI is broken.